# Отображение данных в datagridView при типе данных столбцов int

Tags: c#, sql

У меня есть форма с таблицей связанная с бд sql, и есть форма добавления туда записей.
Некоторые столбцы таблицы имеют тип данных int(первичный ключ), нужно что бы данные добавлялись не в числах ,а в тексте и отображался текст.(если нужно могу скинуть данные, но мне просто объяснить).

Comment: Первичный ключ должна генерить сама БД. Приложение не должно создавать записи указывая первичный ключ. Отправили INSERT - получили id новой записи в таблице обратно. А вопрос я не понял, нужно больше деталей. DataGridView тоже не должна этот ключ отображать, и тем более, не должна давать изменять его пользователю. Ключ служит только для идентификации записей в таблице БД, то ес ь для коммуникации БД с приложением, но не с пользователем.

Comment: Пример. Есть форма для добавления записи в таблицу Сотрудники. У нее есть отношение с таблицей Должности. В таблице Сотрудники есть первичный ключ int и есть пункт Должность тоже с типом int, в таблице Должности есть первичный ключ тоже int. Надо отображалось само название должности а не его первчинйы ключ

Comment: Если еще короче - Мне надо что бы в datagrid отображалось название, а идентификатор

Comment: Так бы сразу и написали. Научитесь использовать SQL запросы с применением JOIN для объединения данных из нескольких таблиц в одном ответе. Это не сложно и решит вашу проблему.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!